# how to re-enable a variable after a package overwrites it? (in particular, mark-even-if-inactive and Hyperbole)

Tags: customize, variables, minor-mode

I have `mark-even-if-inactive` set to `t` in my `init.el`; I've found that I that so `(interative "r")` works as expected; if that variable is `nil`, I get "The mark is not active now" when I try to run my interactive commands.

I can use Customize to set that variable -- but I'm also using Hyperbole, and when hyperbole-mode is loaded, it explicitly sets that variable to `nil`:

```
(defun hyperbole--enable-mode ()
  "Enable Hyperbole global minor mode."
  ;; Store the current value and set `mark-even-if-inactive' to nil so
  ;; can select delimited things if the region is not active when
  ;; hyperbole-mode is enabled.
  (setq hyperbole--mark-even-if-inactive mark-even-if-inactive
    mark-even-if-inactive nil)
; etc etc
```

When I later manually set `mark-even-if-inactive` to `t`, things seem fine, so I'd like to override that behavior of `hyperbole--enable-mode`. What's a good way to do that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you just want to reenable the setting after enabling hyperbole mode? If so, it sounds like Hyperbole likely won't work (it's a *global* minor mode, apparently). Or do you want to make your commands work as if that var were non-nil, even though Hyperbole mode is enabled (and so the variable is nil)? Just what is it that you want to do?

Comment: You can always edit the function (i.e. fork Hyperbole)  and eliminate the setting. I have no idea what that will do to Hyperbole however.

Comment: I want to reenable the setting after enabling hyperbole mode. I'm sure they had *some* good reason for doing that, but I haven't observed any problems, and am willing to suffer the consequences. :) @NickD, yes, I can edit `hyperbole.el`, but I'm curious to know if there's a more elegant or idiomatic way.

Comment: If you don't want to fork Hyperbole, then I would guess (I  haven't actually tried it out) the simplest way is to undo the setting in the `hyperbole-mode-hook`. That would avoid the need to fork Hyperbole, but whether it's elegant or not is in the eye of the beholder. Personally, I would rather fork Hyperbole, but that's just me. The best way however might be to ask the question in the upstream Hyperbole repo (assuming that there is one somewhere): if it gets changed there, then you don't have to worry about it ever again.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I posted your suggestion as the answer.  I'll also look into posting an issue on the Hyperbole repo.

Answer (score 1):

As @NickD points out, probably one of the most idiomatic ways to do this is to use a [mode hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html), in particular `hyperbole-mode-hook`.

I added this to my initialization:

```
(add-hook 'hyperbole-mode-hook (lambda () (setq mark-even-if-inactive t)))
```

and that works.